# Referencing outer context without reassignment

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to reference the context of the outer function without reassigning the context to some local variable?

For example:

```
var objects = [];

// populate objects

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    var outerObject = this;
    $.each(objects, function () {
        this.someMethod(outerObject);
    });
};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [.bind](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind), otherwise, you have to store `this` with a local variable.

```
Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    var outerObject = this;
    var inner = (function () {
        // do something with outerObject
        console.log(this === outerObject);
    }).bind(this);
};
```

***Update:***

For your case:

```
var objects = [];

// populate objects

Foo.prototype.bar = function() {
    $.each(objects, (function (obj) {
        this.someMethod(obj);
    }).bind(this));
};
```

Comment: Oh, sweet! I didn't know about that.

Comment: @Ramin Why not? Nothing conflicted with jQuery.

Comment: That bind call doesn't seem to be of much benefit, I'll stick with the reassignment. :)